# GetChecklists by Id not returning issue ids

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I'm making a call to

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/checklists/v1/containers/:containerid/instances/:instanceId?include=,sections.items,sections.items.attachments
```

I'm finding that entities that I know have issues attached to them do not return issued

`"type": "instance_items"`,

every entity of the above type has it's issuesIds as:

`"issuesIds": null,`

regardless of if there are actually issues.

Is there a parameter I'm missing to ensure these Ids get returned when querying the checklist endpoint?

Comment: It looks the data is missing. I logged the problem with SCCOM-7651

Comment: @XiaodongLiang Thank you, hopefully, they can fix the issue.